# How to chain call hasOne with morphMany?

Tags: laravel

I think the concept relation should easy to understand. just set relations and chain with proper foreign.
I try to chain relation hasOne with morphMany. But hasOne can't access morph relations

> Call to undefined method
> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::images()

```
media model
public function poster(){
  return $this->hasOne(Media::class);
}

poster model
public function images(){
  return $this->morphMany(Image::class, 'imageable');
}

controller
$media = Media::first();

$media->poster()->images()->create();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot chain that way, but you can chain this way:

```php
$media->poster->images()->create()
```

which is short for:

```php
$media->poster()->first()->images()->create()
```

You first need to have a proper `poster` object before you can access the `images`